# Мигает HTML-карта при наведении

Tags: html, css, javascript

Привет. Есть страница http://its116.ru/objects/house-on-nekrasov/ с выбором этажа дома. При наведении на него и сдвиге мышки - этаж мигает. На остальных страницах все ок. Проверял код, там все без изменений. Что может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Трудно сказать, где у вас проблема, но если сделать код, как на этой странице: http://its116.ru/objects/zorge/

Выглядеть он будет вот так:

```
<div id="dom_plan">
  <div id="select_floor" class=""></div>
  <div class="nekrasova" style="display: block; position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1019px; height: 456px; background: url(http://its116.ru/upload/dom_nekrasova.jpg);"></div>
  <div style="position:relative;z-index:51"> 
    <img src="/upload/1x1.gif" width="1020" height="780" border="0" usemap="#Map">
  </div> 
  <map id="Map" name="Map">Тут ваши арии :)</map>
</div>
```

С таким кодом работает всё прекрасно и нажимается

Comment: Спасибо! Так в чем же все таки была проблема?)

Comment: Я пытался разобраться, примерно так это понял: у вас есть элемент, при наведении на который добавляется класс, но когда добавлялся класс, элемент уходил из области наведения (у добавляемого класса был position:absolute), а когда элемент уходил из области наведения, срабатывало событие, по которому этот класс удаляется, и далее события срабатывают на каждый отрезок движения мыши, поэтому когда мышка наведена и неподвижна, то не мигает, а если ей двигать, то происходит интенсивное мигание. Там ещё и canvas зачем-то был, в общем, проще сделать рабочий вариант, чем разобраться, почему баг. :)